# Адаптер для ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Есть активность с ExpandableListView. Есть класс адаптер, который позволяет вывести из json файла инфо о блюдах. Как для ExpandableListView применить данный адаптер?

Вот класс адаптера

```
public class BludoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Bludo> bludoArray;

    BludoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bludo> bludoArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bludoArray = bludoArray;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bludoArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return bludoArray.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        }

        Bludo bludo = getRadio(i);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setText(bludo.title);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients)).setText(bludo.ingredients);
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageResource(bludo.image);
        ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnfavorite)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);

        return view;
    }

    Bludo getRadio(int position) {
        return (Bludo) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Класс Bludo

```
public class Bludo {
    String title;
    String ingredients;
    String description;
    int image;
    String category;
    boolean favorite;

    public Bludo (String title, String ingredients, String description, int image, String category, String favorite) {
        this.title = title;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.favorite = (favorite.equals("1"))? true:false;
    }
}
```

Класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ExpandableListView list;

    //Коллеция для названий категорий (традиционные блюда, сладкое, напитки)
    private String[] categoryNamesArray = new String[] {"Традиционные блюда", "Сладкое", "Напитки"};
    //Коллекция для традиционных блюд
    private ArrayList<String> traditionalDishesArray;
    //Коллекция для сладкого
    private ArrayList<String> sweetArray;
    //Коллекция для напитков
    private ArrayList<String> beveragesArray;
    Map<String, String> map;
    // создаем общую коллекцию для коллекций элементов
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList;

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList;

    private BludoAdapter bludoAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        traditionalDishesArray = new ArrayList<>();
        sweetArray = new ArrayList<>();
        beveragesArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String group : categoryNamesArray) {
            // заполняем список атрибутов для каждой группы
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("groupName", group); // время года
            groupsArray.add(map);
        }

        // список атрибутов групп для чтения
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "groupName" };
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп
        int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        // создаем общую коллекцию для коллекций элементов
        сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();

        // в итоге получится сhildDataList = ArrayList<сhildDataItemList>

        // список атрибутов элементов для чтения
        String childFrom[] = new String[] { "titleName" };
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты
        // элементов
        int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this, groupsArray,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
                groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                childFrom, childTo);

        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Создаем объект класса ParseTask, чтобы парсить JSON и извлечь данные для радио
        new ParseTask().execute();

    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String resultJson = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("lak_kitchen.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            resultJson = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    //Класс парсит JSON и извлекает данные из него
    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return loadJSONFromAsset();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            JSONObject jsonObj = null;

            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray traditionalArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("traditional");

                /*Заполняем категорию традиционные блюда*/
                for (int i = 0; i < traditionalArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = traditionalArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = obj.optString("title");
                    traditionalDishesArray.add(title);
                }

                // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
                сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
                // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
                for (String title : traditionalDishesArray) {
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("titleName", title); // название блюда
                    сhildDataItemList.add(map);
                }
                // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
                сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);
                /*Заполняем категорию традиционные блюда*/

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray sladkoeArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("sladkoe");

                /*Заполняем категорию сладкое*/
                for (int i = 0; i < sladkoeArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = sladkoeArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = obj.optString("title");
                    sweetArray.add(title);
                }

                // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
                сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
                // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
                for (String title : sweetArray) {
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("titleName", title); // название блюда
                    сhildDataItemList.add(map);
                }
                // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
                сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);
                /*Заполняем категорию сладкое*/

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray napitkiArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("napitki");

                /*Заполняем категорию напитки*/
                for (int i = 0; i < napitkiArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = napitkiArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = obj.optString("title");
                    beveragesArray.add(title);
                }

                // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
                сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
                // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
                for (String title : beveragesArray) {
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("titleName", title); // название блюда
                    сhildDataItemList.add(map);
                }
                // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
                сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);
                /*Заполняем категорию напитки*/

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Исключение выкидывает когда пишу

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.test.kitchen/ru.test.kitchen.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: For ExpandableListView, use setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter) instead of setAdapter(ListAdapter)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: For ExpandableListView, use setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter) instead of setAdapter(ListAdapter)
at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:554)
at ru.test.kitchen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:106)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

пишу так

```
 bludoAdapter = new BludoAdapter(this, groupsArray);

        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(bludoAdapter);
```

Comment: я в android еще сам много чего не знаю, но я бы попробовал так `expandableListView.setAdapter(<ваш объект с инициализированным адаптером>);`

Comment: пробовал, но выкидывает исключение. В вопрос добавил исключение